# How can I copy all files while excluding files with a certain pattern?

Tags: linux, command, file-copy

I have the following folder and files:

```
.
├── photos
│   ├── photo-a
│   │   ├── photo-a.meta.json
│   │   └── photo-a.json
│   ├── photo-b
│   │   ├── photo-b.meta.json
│   │   └── photo-b.json
...
There are more folders and files in the photos folder in the same structure
```

I would want to copy all the files `photo-a.json`, `photo-b.json` and others into another folder called `photos-copy`. Basically, I want to exclude all the files that end with `.meta.json` but copy only those that end with `.json` files.

So, if done correctly, `photos-copy` folder would look like this:

```
.
├── photos-copy
│   ├── photo-a.json
│   └── photo-b.json
...
```

I tried something along `cp -a ./photos/*.json ./photos-copy` but this will end up copying everything because the `.meta.json` files also end with `.json` extensions.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A couple of options spring to mind.

```
rsync --dry-run -av --prune-empty-dirs --exclude '*.meta.json' --include '*.json' photos/ photos-copy/
```

Or if you don't have `rsync` (and why not!?), this will copy the files retaining the structure

```
cp -av photos/ photos-copy/
rm -f photos-copy/*/*.meta.json
```

This variant will flatten the files into a single directory

```
cp -av photos/*/*.json photos-copy/
rm -f photos-copy/*.meta.json
```

You can do more fancy things with `bash` and its extended pattern matching, which here tells the shell to match everything that does not contain `.meta` in its name:

```
shopt -s extglob
cp -av photos/*/!(*.meta).json photos-copy/
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the `cp` option! Just one thing, I notice that the files are still copied with their same folder in `photos-copy`. So, instead of copying to `photos-copy/photo-a.json`, they are still copied as `photos-copy/photo-a/photo-a.json`. Is there a way to copy and flatten it by one level to `photos-copy/photo-a.json`?

Comment: @xenon try the extra alternatives I've added

Comment: That's very cool! I tried the example you had with pattern matching, which I thought is cool, but I'm getting a syntax error: `sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('`. Is there something I should take note of when using pattern matching? I have tried with and without the line `shopt -s extglob` and I still got that syntax error.

Comment: Sounds like you're using `sh` rather than `bash`. They're different shells

Comment: Oh, you are right! Thanks again for the help! :)

Comment: The `cp -av photos/*/!(*.meta).json photos-copy/` is very nice :). Thx.

Answer (score 0):

With rsync: `rsync  -rv --include="*/" --exclude="*.meta.json" --include "*.json" --exclude="*"  ./photos/ photo-copy/`

The original directory structure:

```
photo-a/photo-a.json
photo-a/photo-a.meta.json
photo-b/photo-b.json
photo-b/photo-b.meta.json
photo-b/photo-b.son
```

Output:

```
sending incremental file list
photo-a/photo-a.json
photo-b/photo-b.json
```

I tried it with the previous answer (`rsync --dry-run -av --prune-empty-dirs --exclude '*.meta.json' --include '*.json' photos/ photos-copy/`) output:

```
photo-a/photo-a.json
photo-b/
photo-b/photo-b.json
photo-b/photo-b.son
```

Explanation:
In rsync include/exclude the order important.
Include all subdirs 1st. Exclude the meta.json, include .json, and exclude any else.